# Mandatory field validation not working on text input field with placeholder in WordPress Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, validation, placeholder, contact-form-7

I was adding a text field in my form which has a placeholder also it is set as required, but on submit it is not validated for empty field

bellow is the code for that text field

```
<td width="38%" class="f_name1" >
  [text* firstname placeholder class:text_field "First Name" ]
</td>
```

when I am removing the placeholder option them validation is working correctly but with placeholder option it not validating...

Am I following the wrong path to add placeholder?
Any one with any suggestion will help me a lot..

Comment: If you use @Aibrean's code, what do you mean by it's "not validating"? If you leave it blank, it's still allowing the form to be submitted? Can you please post your entire contact form setup in CF7? I'd like to see the other fields.

Comment: Code seems fine. Check once after disabling all other plugins and check also in any one default theme.

Comment: Check  the other jqury confliction on the site that may stop the contact form validation

Comment: Can you post the test of the form you have because I have tried your code and it is working for me.

Comment: what versions of WP and CF7 do you use?  Also: can you share the entire form code and html it produces? we need more details to help you.

Comment: Try the following script replacing the name with your name in a debug console(I use chrome) replacing your-name with the name of the field. `var d = document.getElementsByName('your-name'); console.log(d); d[0].value` to test if there may be extra elements with the same name, or if the value is being set prematurely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably should change the order so the placeholder text is right next to placeholder.

```
  [text* firstname class:text_field placeholder "First Name"]
```

as mentioned in the doc: http://contactform7.com/setting-placeholder-text/
and you need Contact Form 7 3.4 and higher.

Comment: same result in both the case,

Answer (score 0):

Do you try the exact syntax from the documentation first:

```
[text firstname placeholder "First Name"]
```

Then add the class if it succeed:

```
[text firstname placeholder "First Name" class:text_field]
```

And as mentioned in the doc: http://contactform7.com/setting-placeholder-text/ you need Contact Form 7 3.4 or higher.